# Java Cucumber: Feature file generates empty lambda functions with error "Lambda function not expected here"

Tags: java, lambda, cucumber

I'm reviewing a cucumber test automation system written in Java.

When I add a feature file, it generates empty test steps like so:

```
When("the user Clicks on Loan drop down", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});
```

In the actual StepDefs file, however, pasting in the above code always results in an error message: "Lamda Expression not expected here."

How do I get rid of this error or get cucumber to stop generating Step definition functions in Lamda format?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using, and which version of cucumber do you have?

Comment: Also, please post more of your code. Context is important.